# how to declare and update my class in my .cshtml file

Tags: javascript, c#, html, razor

I've create two classes for holding objects in my cshtml file, as below

```
    public GroupBlock groupTemplate = new GroupBlock();

    public RuleBlock ruleTemplate = new RuleBlock();

    public class GroupBlock
    {
        public RuleBlock[] rules { get; set; }
    }

    public class RuleBlock
    {
        public string AndOr { get; set; }
        public string dd1 { get; set; }
        public string dd2 { get; set; }
        public string dd3 { get; set; }
        public string block { get; set; }
    }
```

I now need to declare them in my cshtml file so that I can add data to them whenever a new line is created. My model file is declared as follows

```
@model Client.Web.Models.TaskViewModel
```

I've then tried to declare my two classes as

```
var rules = new @model.ruleTemplate;
var groups = new @model.groupTemplate;
```

This shows a syntax error, what am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying to access my variables in my cshtml file was not working so I shifted the process to my Controller using the following code
            $.ajax({
              type: "GET",
              cache: false,
              data: {"id" : id , "idx" : ruleIndex},
              url: "@Url.Action("UpdateSelectRule")",
              dataType: "html",
              success: function (result) {
                 $("#ajaxResult").html(result);
              }
            });

and accessed the variables from there by creating a 'new' class of my model.

```
 ValidateTaskViewModel model = new validateTaskViewModel();
 model.groupId = id;
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that `GroupBlock` and `RuleBlock` are [nested class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms173120.aspx). How about this :

```
var rules = new TaskViewModel.RuleBlock() ;
var groups = new TaskViewModel.GroupBlock();
```